# AggregateResult query limit

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits

I'm trying to query for all unique accounts that has a first name, last name and person email by using this query:

```
List<AggregateResult> checkUniquePersonAccounts = [
SELECT count(Id), count(FirstName), count(LastName), PersonEmail
FROM Account
WHERE IsPersonAccount = true
GROUP BY PersonEmail
HAVING count(Id) = 1
AND count(FirstName)= 1 
AND count(LastName) = 1
];
```

Obviously this fails if there are more than 2000 records (as that's the limit on records turned by the aggregate function)

What's my workaround, seeing as we've got well over 15k person accounts in the org.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your end objective with this data?

Comment: Incoming cases should be linked to a person account only if the case information that comes in (name and email) exists on one, and one account only

Comment: Then you can obviously add to your `WHERE` clause and only look at records which can match those values, no?

Comment: Well, I might get more than one result then? 
```...SELECT PersonEmail FROM Account WHERE PersonEmail IN :emails```

What if one of the emails in the cases that comes through returns two matches

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment about the end goal here:

> Incoming cases should be linked to a person account only if the case information that comes in (name and email) exists on one, and one account only

I think there's another way to approach this.

Suppose you have a list of Cases, `List<Case> newCases`. Each Case has an `Email` and a first and last name. You want to find those Person Accounts corresponding to the Email and Name, but only if they're unique.

First, process the Cases into three `Set`s: `Set<String> firstNames`, `Set<String>` lastNames`, and`Set emails`. Then, query for all potentially responsive Person Accounts:

```
List<Account> possibleAccounts = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, PersonEmail
    FROM Account
    WHERE IsPersonAccount = true
          AND (FirstName IN :firstNames OR lastName IN :lastNames OR PersonEmail IN :emails)
];
```

Then, process this result list too, into a `Map<String, List<Account>> keyedAccounts` keyed on a *composite key*: the concatenation of the First Name, Last Name, and Email, separated by some delimiter like `\n`. For example, Mike Jones `<mike@jones.com>` would be stored in the `List<Account>` keyed under `Mike\nJones\nmike@jones.com`.

Lastly, walk through your Cases one more time, and for each one construct that composite key. Then, you have your answer as to whether it has one and only one corresponding Account: `keyedAccounts.containsKey(compositeKey) && keyedAccounts.get(compositeKey).size() == 1`.

This is not invulnerable to pathological cases (what if you have 50,000 guys named Carl, for instance?) but it's a pattern you can tailor somewhat to your org's specific data volume and structure and is likely to be more resilient than your current aggregate approach.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the suggestion - not a big fan of concatenating like that - what happens if there are multiple accounts with the same first name + last name + email? I'd still get duplicates then..

Comment: @erikvm I thought that was the point: to determine where you have duplicates and select only those with exactly one matching Account.

Comment: But 
` AND (FirstName IN :firstNames OR lastName IN :lastNames OR PersonEmail IN :emails)`
Doesn't that check if there is a firstname, a last name, OR a person email?

Comment: Yes, it does. The last steps in the process I outline above cover how to use that data to figure out which Cases have exactly one match.

Comment: Hm okay, maybe I misunderstood it a bit - let me try it out and I'll get back - thanks a lot for now

Answer (score 0):

SOQL Pagination may be your answer...

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/tech-pubs/2012/06/the-joys-of-soql-pagination.html

```
List<AggregateResult> checkUniquePersonAccounts = [
   SELECT count(Id), count(FirstName), count(LastName), PersonEmail
   FROM Account
   WHERE IsPersonAccount = true
   GROUP BY PersonEmail
   HAVING count(Id) = 1
      AND count(FirstName)= 1 
      AND count(LastName) = 1
   ORDER BY PersonEmail
   LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000
];
```

Comment: Well this isn't really something thats being rendered in a table or ui, so not sure how pagination helps here

Comment: May need to use a batch process then to break up the query results into batches, that would consolidate the findings. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm

Comment: Something worthy of note: `OFFSET` can only go up to 2000